# HEREDOC text and variables formating issue

Tags: php, heredoc

I created a PHP script that collects variables from HTML and converts them to PHP variables. Then takes those variables and inserts them into a HEREDOC string  and finally sends an email to a predefined person. I'm having an issue getting the text to format with a carriage return after each variable. So that all the text in the email is left side formatted.

What I am getting is this:

SFARC Membership Application Date: February 19th. 2019 First Name: XXXXXX Last Name: XXXXXXX Nick Name: XXXXXXX

Here is portion of my code that handles the text string:

```
// Generate application in a message

    $message = <<<EOT
    SFARC Membership Application
    Date: $App_Date
    First Name: $First_Name
    Last Name: $Last_Name
    Nick Name: $Nick_Name
    Address: $Address
    City/Town: $City_town
    Zip Code: $Zip_code
    Email: $Email
    Home Phone: $Home_phone
    Cell Phone: $Cel_phone
    Callsign: $Call_sign
    ARRL Member: $Arrl_member
    Membership Type: $Membership_type
    Membership Term: $Membership_term year(s)
    Payment Method: $Payment_method
    Membership Dues: $Membership_dues

EOT;

// Sending email
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers )){
   echo 'Your membership application has been successfully submitted.';
} else{
   echo 'Unable to submit your membership application. Please try     
   again.';
};

?>
```

Godaddy is who is hosting my website. Is that the issue? I watched several youtube videos and I have no idea what I am missing? Is there a better way to code to achieve the results I am looking for?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Css Whitespace pre....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your message is send by HTML reason. You can confirm it by content type in the header of email. Or add `$message = nl2br($message);` before send and try again.

Answer (score 0):

You probably tried this, but I want to double check: did you try putting \n or \r at the end of lines?